# How to replace these paths with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, path

I have some objects, linked from other blend-files. I want to get access to their paths in Python, but I can't understand, how to find this data. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These linked files are in:

```
bpy.data.libraries
```

You can have their filepath with for instance:

```
[lib.filepath for lib in bpy.data.libraries]
```

The path is relative to the current blend file, so you can have absolute path with:

```
[bpy.path.abspath(lib.filepath) for lib in bpy.data.libraries]
```

In the documentation:

- [Libraries](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Library.html#module-bpy.types.Library)
- [Path utilities](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.path.html#module-bpy.path)

Comment: Thanks! It works.

Comment: If that works, consider to accept the answer @Mapper720, thanks. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour